# How to interfere when user presses CTRL+X and still keep TMemo's default CTRL+X behavior?

Tags: delphi, clipboard, onchange, copy-paste, tmemo

I have a `TMemo` on the form and I've set an `OnChange` event for it. I hope the `OnChange` event not to be triggered when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> in the memo. But <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> just cuts the text selection, which will for sure trigger the `OnChange` event. How can I prevent that?

I've tried to detect <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> in the `KeyUp` event, and if the user pressed <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> I unbind the memo's `OnChange` event and programmatically cut the text again. But this doesn't work, and I don't how to programmatically send <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = Ord('X')) and (Shift = [ssCtrl]) then
  begin
    Memo1.OnChange := nil;
    // programmatically cut the text here, which I don't know how to do
    Memo1.OnChange := Memo1Change;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Pressing [SHIFT+DEL also cuts to the clipboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#Common_keyboard_shortcuts) - that's the legacy shortcut which existed before CTRL+V was hyped and is still supported/must be expected.

Comment: @AmigoJack Will the WM_CUT message cover it?

Comment: Why not trying it out yourself? It should, just like right clicking and selecting "cut" from the context menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on keyboard events (They are not executed for example when you cut something by using the popupmenu), rely on windows messages instead.

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FPrevMemoWindowProc : TWndMethod;
    procedure MemoWindowProc(var AMessage: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Clipbrd;

procedure TForm1.MemoWindowProc(var AMessage: TMessage);
begin
  if(AMessage.Msg = WM_CUT) then
  begin
    if(Memo1.SelLength > 0) then
    begin
      Memo1.OnChange := nil;
      try
        Clipboard.AsText := Memo1.SelText;
        Memo1.ClearSelection();
        Exit;
      finally
        Memo1.OnChange := Memo1Change;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  FPrevMemoWindowProc(AMessage);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPrevMemoWindowProc := Memo1.WindowProc;
  Memo1.WindowProc := MemoWindowProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Change');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried it and ctrl x doesn't trigger OnChange event, which is cool. But by my testing, it seems the cut text isn't copied to clipboard. See this image: https://i.imgur.com/7dRf7XK.gif

Comment: Because this code's logic is flawed: assigning `Clipboard.AsText` must come before assigning `Memo1.Text` - move it 2 lines up. As it stands now you'll always set the clipboard to an empty text, which can be pasted, too. No idea why 4 people upvote without seeing this mistake.

Comment: That's why you should always test your code before posting an answer at SO! In any case, why make it so complicated? Why not simply do `Clipboard.AsText := Memo1.SelText; Memo1.ClearSelection;`?

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanation. 95% percent of the answer is correct and I've learned a lot from it!

Comment: I've updated the answer by applying the suggested fix and simplification